# Unexpected empty set solution while using `Solve`

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve a system of five equations and five variables w.r.t. one of them. I do not understand I obtain the empty set if I try to solve

```
Solve[x+y==s && x==p*Cos[a] && y==q*Cos[b] && h^2+x^2==p^2 && h^2+y^2==q^2 && 0<a<\[Pi]/4 && 0<b<\[Pi]/4, {x}, Reals]
```

However, if I reduce the above equality system to a simple quadratic equation in $x$, I obtain a non-empty solution set:

```
Solve[(1/(Cos[a]^2))*x^2+(1+1/(Cos[b]^2))*s*x-s^2==0 && 0<a<\[Pi]/4 && 0<b<\[Pi]/4, {x}, Reals]
```

Please find attached this screenshot:[image]

Could you please help me to understand where is the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have five equations and specify only one unknown, the rest of the variables being treated as parameters. `Solve` does better if the number of unknowns equals the number of equations (not a strict requirement perhaps, though in many cases, such as this one, it seems necessary):

```
Solve[x + y == s && x == p*Cos[a] && y == q*Cos[b] && 
  h^2 + x^2 == p^2 && h^2 + y^2 == q^2 && 0 < a < \[Pi]/4 && 
  0 < b < \[Pi]/4, {x}, {y, p, q, h}, Reals]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you! I was expecting an answer from Mathematica in terms of $s, a, b$, but I now read the numerical answer $45.8559$. Why?

Comment: @PenelopeBenenati You're welcome. :) If you get a numerical answer, I think it must be because you set the variables equal to some numbers. It's never happened to me otherwise.

Comment: @PenelopeBenenati Note his image includes `//AbsoluteTiming`, which is used to report the time cost of the evaluation. `45.8559` means that `Solve` cost `45.8559 seconds`

Comment: @rnotlnglgq Thanks, I misread/misunderstood Penelope's comment.  I included the timing to warn folks it takes a long time.

Comment: `Simplify` gives a cleaner result; i.e., `Assuming[0 < a < \[Pi]/4 && 0 < b < \[Pi]/4, Solve[x + y == s && x == p*Cos[a] && y == q*Cos[b] && h^2 + x^2 == p^2 && h^2 + y^2 == q^2, {x}, {y, p, q, h}, Reals] // Simplify]`